# Adding a C++ Header to Objective-C project

Tags: objective-c

I've got a strange error working with Photoshop connection API in OSx. 
I need to include the header of a cpp file to my project... I start from the adobe example and I included the code in this way:

```
#include "PSCryptor.h"
```

which contains the PSCryptor class :

```
class PSCryptor
{
    public:
...
```

As soon as i try to use PSCrypor object, like with this code

```
static PSCryptor *sPSCryptor = NULL;
```

I get this error:

```
Unknown type name 'class'; did you mean 'Class'?
```

Could you help me to understand which is my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is being included in Objective-C files — that is, they have the extension ".m" or they are specifically configured to be compiled as Objective-C (probably the former). Thus, the compiler tries to interpret the code as Objective-C, but C++ is not valid Objective-C, so it complains.

What you need to do is use Objective-C++ instead. Simple fix: change the extension of the files that use that header from ".m" to ".mm".

Comment: the example used by Adobe works with a .cpp file, in your opinion how is this possible ?

Comment: @MatterGoal: .cpp files are also compiled as C++, so that wouldn't be a problem. It sounds like the trouble you're having is that you're importing this header in a file that is *not* C++.

Comment: @Chunk you're right! i can modify the extension with .mm or modify "file type" property in "identity and Type" box.